# rebuild numpy array, need faster method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have image numpy array (640,480,3) where X,Y is coordinates and (255 255 255) is a color mask for point

I try to get new 2d array(x,y), where X and Y is coordinates for point when color > zero..

I try this code
and it works, but it takes too much processor time

```
enter code here
for x in range(edges.shape[0]):
     for y in range(edges.shape[1]):
          if edges[[x],[y],[0]]!=0:
             new.append([x,y])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the first element of last axis, compare it against `0` and then use `np.argwhere` to get those indices, which would be the `x`, `y` coordinates in a `(N,2)` shaped array.

Thus, the implementation would be simply  -

```
new = np.argwhere( edges[...,0]!=0 )
```